# Pandas: Why does DataFrame.drop(labels) return a DataFrame with removed label name

Tags: python, pandas

When I drop some variables from a DataFrame, dataframe return as I expect except the when index.name is removed. Why would this be?

Example:

```
test = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[3,4,5],[5,6,7]], index=['a','b','c'], columns=['d','e','f'])
test

Out[20]:
second  d   e   f
first           
a   1   2   3
b   3   4   5
c   5   6   7
#test.index.name = first
#test.columns.name=second
In [27]:

test.drop(['b'])

Out[27]:
second  d   e   f
a   1   2   3
c   5   6   7
```

After 'b' is dropped the returned dataframe `(index.name)` is no longer 'first' but None.

Q1. Is it because the `.drop()` method returns a dataframe that has a
    new index object which by default would have no name?
Q2. Is there anyway to preserve the `index.name` during drop operations as the newindex is still correctly named - it is just a subset of the
    original index

Expected Output would be:

```
 Out[20]:
    second  d   e   f
    first           
    a   1   2   3
    c   5   6   7
```

Comment: do you mean you want to drop the `'b'` row but keep the `'b'` label for the row with `[5,6,7]`?

Comment: No I would like to drop the 'b' row but keep the entire Index in the new dataframe as the same name as before. (i.e. a,c would be named 'first')

Comment: Please edit your question to include your _expected_ or _desired_ output.

Comment: I think it's confusing to use the word label in the context you mean.  I think you mean you want to keep the index `name`

Comment: Updated to remove label and use name. Yes - index.name is what I am referring to. Thanks.

Comment: Looking at the source code it doesn't look like drop saves the index name when it reindexes the axis.

Comment: This looks like a bug to me. Posting here: https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/2939

Comment: I put in a pull request for a fix of this.

Answer (score 1):

One way to achieve the intended behavior is:

```
row_name = test.index.name
test = test.drop('b')
test.index.name = row_name
```

But this isn't ideal.